# page jumps to top on menu click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I am creating a website with a fixed menu on the left, the menu is visible on click with jQuery. My problem is that when I am scrolled down to the bottom of the page and I want to bring the menu into view the page jumps back to the top. I would like the page to stay in its current position when clicking on the menu. How can I do this?

This is the jQuery thats animates the menu in and out:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#closeIcon").hide()
  });

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menuIcon").click(function(){
    $(".left").animate({width:'10%'}, "500");
    $(".right").animate({width:'90%'}, "500");
    $("#nav").animate({
                left: '30%',
              }, "500" );
    $("#menuIcon").fadeOut(500)
    $("#closeIcon").fadeIn(500)


  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#closeIcon").click(function(){
    $(".left").animate({width:'0%'}, "500");
    $(".right").animate({width:'100%'}, "500");
    $("#nav").animate({
                left: '0',
            }, "500" );
    $("#menuIcon").fadeIn(500)
    $("#closeIcon").fadeOut(500)

  });
});
```

The menu itself is positioned outside the page, on click it slides in and the main page resizes.

Comment: is "#closeIcon" a link? If so, you're missing your e.preventDefault() on the click event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds very much like an anchor tag issue.  Without seeing the HTML I will wager that:

Your  tag ("#closeIcon") needs to set javascript:void(0) on click to stop it from readjusting the page position.  Mind posting up the html?

Comment: yes no problem I will post the html in the form of an answer, although if my answer would be to set void(0) how exactly would I do this? where would that fit in to the javascript / jquery I have already written?

Comment: @user1324925 Awesome, glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

Anchor tag on which javascript function is defined to show/hide menu should have attribute `href="javascript:void(0)"`.

Answer (score 1):

Another one properly working decision;

```
<...>
$("#menuIcon").click(function(){
    <...>
    return false;
});    

$("#closeIcon").click(function(){
    <...>
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This is the one working for me, I wasn't using <a> tags.

Answer (score 0):

This is the html for the Icon buttons, that open and close the menu:

```
   <div id="menu">
      <a href="#"><img id="menuIcon" src="images/menuIcon.png"></a>
      <a href="#"><img id="closeIcon" src="images/closeIcon.png"></a>
    </div>
```

This is the html for the menu which opens on click:

```
<div class="left">
     <div id="nav">                     
        <div id="accordion">
              <!-- accordion menu goes here -->         
    </div> <!--ends accordion-->    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same - my solution was to remove the href="#" which I had on the `<a>` tag of the menu icon.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of use in some situations

```
<a href="#dummydiv">Services</a>
```

Create a div named dummydiv with no attributes, since the div is not actually used anywhere when you click on a menu item nothing will move. This is useful for flyout menus on Mobil devices in particular when you do not want things jumping all over the page.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar problem here: [Prevent background scrolling when overlay appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918560/prevent-background-scrolling-when-overlay-appears/70584981#70584981)

The gist: use the `overflow:hidden` property on the `html` tag rather than the `body`.

Here is your code revised:

```css
.lock-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#closeIcon").hide()
  });

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menuIcon").click(function(){
    $('html').addClass('lock-scroll');
    $(".left").animate({width:'10%'}, "500");
    $(".right").animate({width:'90%'}, "500");
    $("#nav").animate({
                left: '30%',
              }, "500" );
    $("#menuIcon").fadeOut(500)
    $("#closeIcon").fadeIn(500)


  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#closeIcon").click(function(){
    $('html').removeClass('lock-scroll');
    $(".left").animate({width:'0%'}, "500");
    $(".right").animate({width:'100%'}, "500");
    $("#nav").animate({
                left: '0',
            }, "500" );
    $("#menuIcon").fadeIn(500)
    $("#closeIcon").fadeOut(500)

  });
});
```